# How can I uninstall Antivirus Studio 2010 completely?

Tags: uninstall, malware

Is Antivirus Studio 2010 malware? I found it installed on my computer yesterday, and I try to uninstall it with Control Panel. But I noticed that it is still running! How can I uninstall it completely?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, its malware. [This site](http://www.uninstallerdownload.com/instruction-on-uninstalling-antivirus-studio-2010-know-how-to-uninstall-antivirus-studio-2010-completely.html) will help you get rid of it. Just follow all the steps and if doesn't clear it up for you then let me know.